# Dell Latitude E5430 laptop running Windows 7 - external monitor won't connect to computer

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, vga, external-display, dell-latitude

Please help!!
I have a Dell Latitude E5430 laptop running Windows 7 64-bit and my external monitor is no longer connecting to the computer. I have been connecting it with a VGA cable and it was working as of Friday, then when I attempted on Saturday it would not connect, the monitor says "No Signal". When I go to Screen Resolution, I'm given the option of extending the screen, duplicating, etc. And when the screen is "extended" windows will disappear into the screen, but the screen will still not display. But the same options appear and the same thing happens with the extended display even with the VGA cord is NOT plugged into the computer.

I know this is not a problem with the monitor because I have now tried 3 different monitors with 3 different cables that have all worked previously with my computer and work now with other computers. I'm worried it might be a hardware issue with the VGA port.

Other things I've tried, but did not work: 
- Updating my video driver
- System restore - first back to Saturday, then back 2 weeks

Please let me know if you have any ideas!